# Outlooks adding space in HTML tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, outlook

I am sending html emails using python, it works good ,but outlook ( 2016 ) spontaneously adding spaces between random HTML tags, for example:

I am sending:

`<td valign="top" align="right" class="someClass"><span>text</text>`

I am receiving:

`< td valign="top" align="right" class="someClass"><span>text</text>`

and I see tags instead of formatted text.

Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure, that it is outlooks fault? Have you viewed the mail source itself?

Comment: Yes, I've printed raw code and checked in browser.Works okay

Comment: The solution is to post your html code. It sounds like you have an issue with a stray `"`. Also, `<span>text</text>` isn't valid.

Comment: Hi Gwally , thanks for your response. I've put all code in the separate topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158995/how-to-send-email-via-python-with-html-tags-standard-solution-does-not-work

Comment: Hi, I've found the solution. I had to change the following line and add utf8 coding: `html = MIMEText( self.getHtmlTemplate() , 'html', "utf-8")`